# how to load selected data from database and display in textbox in another form

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, selectedindex

so i have two forms. one is the main form which contains a listbox of deliveries, where data gets loaded from a database. the other form is the delivery form which when the user selects the delivery from the listbox, its details should get displayed in the delivery form.
so far i have managed to load the data in and managed to get some text displayed in my deliveryform. however, i cannot get my deliveryform to display the data of the selected delivery from the list box.

here is a bit of my code:

```
private void FrmDelivery_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data  Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\visits.mdf;Integrated  Security=True;User Instance=True");
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CustomerName, CustomerAddress, ArrivalTime FROM   tblVisits", con);
SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (sdr.Read())
{
this.txtCustomerName.Text = sdr["CustomerName"].ToString(); 
this.txtCustomerAddress.Text = sdr["CustomerAddress"].ToString();
this.txtArrivalTime.Text = sdr["ArrivalTime"].ToString();
}

sdr.Close();

if (theDelivery != null)
{
txtCustomerName.Text = theDelivery.customerName;
txtCustomerAddress.Text = theDelivery.customerAddress;
txtArrivalTime.Text = theDelivery.arrivalTime;
}
}
```

Comment: change Modifiers properties of theDelivery Form control, eg. theDelivery.txtCustomerName.Modifiers  = Public   ||                  if (theDelivery != null)
{
theDelivery.txtCustomerName.Text = "Abc";
theDelivery.txtCustomerAddress.Text = "Abc";
theDelivery.txtArrivalTime.Text = "---"
}

Answer (score 0):

I would use this way:

```
public string Get_Field(SqlConnection con, string Table,string Field,string where)
{

       DataSet RS_Temp = new DataSet();
       SqlDataAdapter DA;
       string SqlStr = "SELECT " &  Field &  " FROM " & Table;

       //Add an "If statment" if there is a where condition....

       DA = new OleDbDataAdapter(SqlStr, con);
       DA.Fill(RS_Temp, Table_Name);

            if (RS_Temp.Tables[Table_Name].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                return ("");
            }
            if (System.Convert.IsDBNull(RS_Temp.Tables[Table_Name].Rows[0][0]))
            {
                return ("");
            }

            if (RS_Temp.Tables[Table_Name].Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                return (RS_Temp.Tables[Table_Name].Rows[0][0].ToString());
            }
            return ("");

}
```

Dont forget to add Try & catch of course then:

```
YOURTEXTBOX.Text = Get_Field(...)
```